# string to date conversion - .NET different behaviour

Tags: vb.net

Please see the below code:

```
 Dim dtEstComplDate As Date
 Try
    dtEstComplDate = "08-mar-16"
 Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

If I set my computers local format as English (united states), `'08-mar-16'` gets assigned to `dtEstComplDate` as `#3/82016#`
Now, If I change my computers format to Italian, this assignment results in the following exception:

> "Conversion from string "08-mar-16" to type 'Date' is not valid."

I tried with `08-mrz-16` with italian setting. It did not work.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `mar` is the abbreviation for the month march in english not in italian.

Don't use strings to initialize dates. Instead you should change `Option Strict` to `On`. Then you'll learn a lot about .NET methods and types and how to write type safe code. If you want to initialize a Date you can use the constructor: `dtEstComplDate = New Date(2016, 3, 8)`.

If you really have to parse a string to `Date` use `Date.Parse`/`Date.TryParse` or [`Date.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)/`Date.TryParseExact`:

```
dtEstComplDate = Date.ParseExact("08-mar-16", "dd-MMM-yy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

I'm using `InvariantInfo` because it's derived from the english format.

Comment: Agreed. But if I provide the Italian abbreviation for March , it should work right?

Comment: @Sameer: yes, so it depends if you want to ensure that you can parse english names even if the current culture is italian or if you want to parse both, then you have to know the source format.

Comment: I agree with Data.Parse approach, but sticking to my old point, I checked several sites for Italian month name abbreviations. Most of them list 'Mar' only. As I have given above, I have tried with 'Mrz' as well. Both dont work.

Comment: @Sameer: you're right, i don't know italian but it seems that the abbraviation is the same. So it works even if you use `Date.ParseExact("08-mar-16", "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo("it-IT"))` so using the italian culture. But that does not mean that your implicit conversion from string to date works that way. Don't use this magical conversions. Change to option strict and fix the compiler errors. You'll benefit from it in future.

Answer (score 0):

try this its more simple to convert any to date
MsgBox(CDate("01/02/16").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
the cdate function will convert your text to date

Answer (score 0):

I hope below example will help you to understand .. why these happend.. when you changing region in regional setting .. same thing happening here by dot net code ...

```
    Dim dtEstComplDate As Date
    Try

        'Will be the country name you set using datetimesetting
        MessageBox.Show(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)

        Dim ukCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
        Dim itCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

        ukCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
        itCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT")

        Dim strDate = "08-mar-16"

        'forcing to use uk culture when converting string to date
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ukCulture

        dtEstComplDate = strDate
        MessageBox.Show(dtEstComplDate)

        'forcing to use italian culture when converting string to date
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = itCulture
        dtEstComplDate = strDate
        MessageBox.Show(dtEstComplDate)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: i agree that Date.Parse is a better way to convert string into date by passing cultureInfo parameter. But in my question above I have given a legacy piece of code as is. So if one culture accepts direct string to date assignation , other culture should also accept it given the string value is in correct format.

Comment: May be my example approach was wrong .. i did not recommended to use  `date.parse` here .. i just wanted to help you how .. it's working .. and why you getting exception .. please look on my edit ... i think it's better now .. :)

Comment: your reply made me dig deeper into the code and what I found is that during initialization they are setting:  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
            CultProvider = New CultureInfo("it-IT")    . So looking at your example, Setting CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = en-US is the line which is causing trouble. Isnt it?

Comment: @Sameer .. that's great .. and my intention was also to show you why .. different behaviour ..